# How do I use the "%" math expression?

Tags: flutter, dart, math

Hi I'm trying to make a calculator app and I want to use the "%" math expression but the result is "Error". How do I solve this?.

...........................................................................................................................................................................................................

[image]

...........................................................................................................................................................................................................

This is my code:

```
String equation = "";
String result = "";
String expression = "";
double equationFontSize = 38.0;
double resultFontSize = 48.0;



buttonPressed(String buttonText) {
setState(() {
  if (buttonText == "AC") {
    equation = "";
    result = "";
    equationFontSize = 38.0;
    resultFontSize = 48.0;
  } else if (buttonText == "⌫") {
    equationFontSize = 48.0;
    resultFontSize = 38.0;
    equation = equation.substring(0, equation.length - 1);
    if (equation == "") {
      equation = "0";
    }
  } else if (buttonText == "=") {
    equationFontSize = 38.0;
    resultFontSize = 48.0;

    expression = equation;
    expression = expression.replaceAll('×', '*');
    expression = expression.replaceAll('÷', '/');
    expression = expression.replaceAll('^', '^');
    expression = expression.replaceAll('%', '%');

    try {
      Parser p = Parser();
      Expression exp = p.parse(expression);
      ContextModel cm = ContextModel();
      result = "${exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, cm)}";
      _isIntResult();
    } catch (e) {
      result = "Error";
    }
  } else if (buttonText == "⌞⌝") {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
  } else {
    equationFontSize = 48.0;
    resultFontSize = 38.0;
    if (equation == "") {
      equation = buttonText;
    } else {
      equation = equation + buttonText;
    }
  }
});
}


_isIntResult() {
if (result.toString().endsWith(".0")) {
  result = int.parse(result.toString().replaceAll(".0", "")).toString();
 }
}
```

Comment: % can be two things: either the modulo operator (which returns the remainder of the division), or the percentage of something (as in 25% of 8 is 2). It's not really clear which one you need: also, it would be nice to have the full text of the error

Comment: I don't quite understand the explanation that you gave to me. It doesn't show the error text in the android studio. But It shows the  "Error" text from the result of the equation in the app. (I'm still a beginner)

Comment: It was more asking for clarification that explaining: I don't know for sure which mathematical operation you're trying to perform, so I don't know how to help you. I am also supposing that the error on the app is coming from some error reported in the Android Studio console output, and that you might add it to the question in order to understand better what's going wrong

Comment: No, it doesn't show the error in the Android Studio console output. I want the result to be 0.25. And I'm kinda confused because, when I tried it manually like 25/100 the result shows the number / 0.25, but when I use the % the result is Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Eg:

```
10%===>10/100=.1

 10%100===>10
```

**Logic**
here /100 - constant
10%======>     10/100=.1
10%100===>     (10/100)*100=10

```
  var count = text.replaceAll("=", "").replaceAll("", "").split("%");
  if (count.length == 2) {
    if(count[1].isNotEmpty) {
      var s = (int.parse(count[0]) / 100) * int.parse(count[1]);
      setState(() {
        _textcontroller.text = s.toString();
      });
    }else{
      var s = int.parse(count[0]) / 100;
      setState(() {
        _textcontroller.text = s.toString();
      });
    }
  } else if (count.length == 1 ||count.length == 2) {
    var s = int.parse(count[0]) / 100;
    setState(() {
      _textcontroller.text = s.toString();
    });
  }
```

Calculation working here

```
     void SetMytext(String clickedvalue) {
    var text = _textcontroller.text;
    // var calc = clickedvalue;

    if (clickedvalue == "C") {
      setState(() {
        _textcontroller.text = "";
      });
    } else if (clickedvalue == "=") {
      var count = text.replaceAll("=", "").replaceAll("", "").split("%");
      if (count.length == 2) {
        if(count[1].isNotEmpty) {
          var s = (int.parse(count[0]) / 100) * int.parse(count[1]);
          setState(() {
            _textcontroller.text = s.toString();
          });
        }else{
          var s = int.parse(count[0]) / 100;
          setState(() {
            _textcontroller.text = s.toString();
          });
        }
      } else if (count.length == 1 ||count.length == 2) {
        var s = int.parse(count[0]) / 100;
        setState(() {
          _textcontroller.text = s.toString();
        });
      }
      // setState(() {
      //   _textcontroller.text = text + clickedvalue;
      // });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _textcontroller.text = text + clickedvalue;
      });
    }
  }
```

**SAmpleCode**  [Dartpad Live Code check](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c6effcb8c7dd6532640a50a1bc0accdf)

```
  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String? title;

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

var _dropdown1 = "1";
var _textcontroller = TextEditingController();

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int selected = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  var list = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "%", "=", "C"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // theme: theme(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  controller: _textcontroller,
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                // height: 150,
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                  children: [
                    ...list.map((e) {
                      return ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            SetMytext(e.toString());
                          },
                          child: Text(e.toString()));
                    }).toList()
                  ],
                ),
              )
              // ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("="))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  void SetMytext(String clickedvalue) {
    var text = _textcontroller.text;
    // var calc = clickedvalue;

    if (clickedvalue == "C") {
      setState(() {
        _textcontroller.text = "";
      });
    } else if (clickedvalue == "=") {
      var count = text.replaceAll("=", "").replaceAll("", "").split("%");
      if (count.length == 2) {
        if(count[1].isNotEmpty) {
          var s = (int.parse(count[0]) / 100) * int.parse(count[1]);
          setState(() {
            _textcontroller.text = s.toString();
          });
        }else{
          var s = int.parse(count[0]) / 100;
          setState(() {
            _textcontroller.text = s.toString();
          });
        }
      } else if (count.length == 1 ||count.length == 2) {
        var s = int.parse(count[0]) / 100;
        setState(() {
          _textcontroller.text = s.toString();
        });
      }
      // setState(() {
      //   _textcontroller.text = text + clickedvalue;
      // });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _textcontroller.text = text + clickedvalue;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But when I want to add something like 29% + 5 = 1.45.It should be 5.29.What is the problem?

Comment: change your equation (29/100)+5.you need to modify in this condition